# Simple cross-platform 3D scene render for Python

Tags: python, 3d, cross-platform, render

I have a code in Python that simulates planetary orbits. It currently uses Visual Python (VPython) to render the 3D scene, however it only works in Linux through wine and needs some work around.

Now I'm looking for a completely cross-platform render to use in my simulator. Nothing fancy, I just need to place some spheres, rotate and change their positions. I don't need any powerful game engine. The simpler, the better.

Do you know of any 3D scene render that could help me with this?

(I hope this does not fit into the "Opinion based question" that gets closed here :( )

Comment: I hate to have to tell you this, but requests for libraries & other off-site resources are also off-topic on SO. However, you may find [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net) of interest. It's not exactly simple, but it _is_ cross-platform.

Comment: Oh, too bad :( . I'll try this PyOpenGL, I've some experience with OpenGL, perhaps it will not be much different. Thanks for the suggestion and the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while, so I am not sure if this question is still of interest. I've been looking into rendering libraries for similar purposes, and [blender](https://www.blender.org/) seems to be an option. It has a python scripting interface (called bpy). It is not a library: you have to run your python program within blender's python interpreter (you can't just call it from a python interpreter), but it looks like you can run arbitrary python code. And it appears to be cross-platform.